# Command taking priority over Submodule group Discord.Net

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm trying to set up a few nested commands using groups, but commands of the parent group seem to be taking priority.

Here is an example of my code.

```
[Group("foo"), Summary("Testing foo")]
public class TestModule : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
{
    [Group("bar"), Summary("Testing bar")]
    public class TestModTwo : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        [Command, Summary("bar default command")]
        public async Task Test()
        {
            await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("bar default command");
        }
    }

    [Command, Summary("foo default command")]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("foo default command");
    }

    [Command, Summary("foo default command with string")]
    public async Task Test(string User)
    {
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("foo default command with string");
    }
}
```

When running my command `w?foo bar` my bot returns "foo default command with string" instead of the desired "bar default command". Commenting out my test method with a string returned what I want. Is there a way to specify my nested command while still having the ability to accept a string in the parent group command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve such a behavior by adding a `PriorityAttribute` on your inner command. This will tell Discord.net to check for this command first.

Note: The highest number insert to the `PriorityAttribute` will get checked first!